# Custom ADR Software

Tags: adr, software, custom, recording, foley

Hey guys,

I know I asked a similar question earlier and I really don't mean to beat a dead horse,

But, I would like to create a custom ADR cueing program.

Basically, all I really need is the ability to send beeps and streamers at specific time-code points that are triggerable at whatever point of the recording process. Most importantly, as Pro Tools rolls so I don't have to stop recording and re-punch the actor in to give him beeps/streamers. Let me be more specific:

I have done a few feature films so far (ADR and foley recording) and I have been using ADR Studio Pro. This program is okay but it doesn't send cues as it records. For example, an actor I recorded requested beeps and streamers at the beginning of each paragraph (he says 3 paragraphs in a row) and I had to tell him I couldn't do that because ADR Studio only sends one beep/streamer at a time (I.E. only when you initiate the recording). What he wanted to do is continue recording through the whole scene and be sent beeps/streamers at each of the beginning of a paragraph.

Is there something I could buy (midi or whatever) that could read Pro Tools markers or midi events ahead of time in order for it to send beeps/streamers as it records? Like if the actor wants to record all 3 paragraphs in a row?

It's also specifically asked for when I record Foley and the sound designer wants to record foley for a whole scene (Robin Hood for example) and he wants cues at each time the actor begins walking and wants beeps/streamers there and not have to stop and have me re-punch on the spot?

Any information on this is extremely valuable as I am having another recording session soon.

Thanks a lot in advance. Your help is much appreciated.

- Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Now, I've never used streamers but whenever I've done ADR the actors have been happy with beeps. I simply create a track within PT and place my pre-made beeps region so it's end is where their line begins. Add markers in and I can slide or copy the region about quiet happily to keep up with actor as needs be.

I demo'd VoiceQ a couple of years ago and it offered a streamers visual cue on the QT movie you load up. I loved the software apart from its seeming instability. I know that many swear by it but I just couldn't get it to be happy on any of the Mac PT systems, either HD or LE, G5 or Intel.

A quick Google search just gave me http://figure53.com/streamers. I might have a proper look at this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah - Birdhouse recommended Figure 53 on the last post and I am mid checking it out right now. Thanks a lot!